# Upgrade to Angular 6 and the Test is not working

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-upgrade

I initiated a project using Angular 5. After some development, I upgraded to Angular 6.

After upgrade to Angular 6, doing some adjustment to the development code.

But, I'm facing this issue when I run the `Test`.

[image]

Based on what I got, I'm missing `'rxjs-compat/Observable'` module.

So I just install `npm install rxjs-compat --save` and run `'ng test'`.

The error is not showing anymore. But I'm facing new problem.

Now, the error is `No captured browser`.

[image]

Is there any idea about this?

### What I have done

- Upgrade both *local* and *global* `angular-cli`.
- Delete all `node_modules` and re-install the new one

### Additional Information

Here is the angular version I used :

[image]

Comment: Have you ran ´karma start´ in the same directory as your karma.json?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Hi @Maartenw i'm so sorry, I just see the answer now. and previously i fixed it the way i create the answer in the comment.

Comment: Hi @halfer, thank you for the reminder :)

Comment: Please refrain from adding `code formatting` to proper nouns. The names of software libraries like Angular are _not_ themselves code, and should just be rendered in the correct case, nothing more. Thank you.

Comment: @halfer Okay, thank you for telling me :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `karma init` in the same directory as your `karma.conf.js`
2. Make sure that your karma conf file includes `Chrome`
3. Run `karma start` in the same directory as your `karma.conf.js` file.

Let me know if it helped

Comment: Hi, I already fixed my current problem. But I dont know if it is actually a fix or not. I'm rename current project folder to project-bak and then create a new project `ng new project`. And i copy all the `src` folder, and the `style.scss` to new project.

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading to Angular 6, you also need to upgrade to RxJS 6 API syntax. You need to rewrite your import statements associated to observable methods and rxjs-compat needs to be removed.

You can find more detailed instructions in the Angular Upgrade Guide https://update.angular.io/ (set it to upgrade from 5.2 to 6).

Comment: In the OP she has ran the npm insdtall rxjs-compat package which should automatically install RxJS6 and update dependencies accordingly

Comment: Mmh. In the Angular Upgrade Guide it states: "Once you and all of your dependencies have updated to RxJS 6, remove rxjs-compat." The console screenshot however states that there is a type reference to rxjs-compat/Observable.

Answer (score 0):

## Quick fix for my current problem (From Angular 5 to Angular 6)

### Step 1 : Rename current project to `{project-name}-bak`

### Step 2 : Make Sure your global Angular Version is the latest version

For this step, my global version is **6.1.3**.

You can check your global version via `ng -v` outside your Angular Project.

### Step 3 : Create a new Angular 6 project

Create a new Angular project using your *project-name*.

`ng new project-name`

### Step 4 : Try to run the test

Run the test `ng test` to make sure if your newly generated Angular 6 project is working well.

### Step 5 : Move your code (only if your Step 4 is ok)

- Replace the `src` folder with the `src` from **`{project-name}-bak`**
- Copy your `styles.css` or `styles.scss` and all you global stylesheet from **`{project-name}-bak`**
- If you have stylesheet other than `styles.css` or `styles.scss`, you should update your `angular.json`.
- Try to run the test `ng test` again. ***<sub><sup>(For me, it works until here)</sup></sub>***

**Note : If anyone have a better way to fix, please updates on comment, maybe another people can be helped.**